# Interpolation - can anyone explain it better?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, spatial, cubic-spline

[image]

vq3 = grid data interpolations with methods 'cubic' *(matrix 21x21)*

vq = interpolated values *(matrix 21x21)*

I don't understand what `j,j` is?

Comment: From whence did this set of symbols come? From what tutelage or tome did you locate this?

Comment: vq is retrieved form the standard gridata function in matlab. vq3 from griddata interpolations using the cubic method.

Comment: @ 500 Server error: By including  this information when you first posted this question, it would enable us to answer your inquiry correctly, minimize the risk of down votes and direct you to the correct site as appropriate.

Comment: @bbpy-newb got it immediately what the question is about. vq3 and vq are also explained above in the question

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow. It has nothing to do with programming. Please read the [ask], which you should have done long ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equation is referring to the diagonal elements.
You can see this by visualizing the matrix at each cell with co-ordinates  row =j, column =j.

Comment: that's what I thought but I'm afraid I was interpreting it wrong. I can compute the diagram, but what about the max?

Comment: When you compute n differences at cells (0,0) to (n,n) you will have n results. The maximum of those n results would be your answer.